# IOptionsMonitor stops updating

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are running into a weird issue and we need help to pinpoint what the cause is. We are using Azure App Configuration and our IOptionsMonitor values stop receiving updates, but we can see the configuration is updating.

It is an ASP.NET Core app and when running locally it runs fine. We have been able to recreate the issue locally, by enabling Application Insights locally. We have created a test API that shows an optionsmonitor value and the configuration debug view. We can see the optionsmonitor and debug view updating just fine at startup. Once we execute another API controller, then the optionsmonitor stops updating, but we can see debug view with the updates.

We have reduced one of the other endpoints down to just returning a string, but it still causes the updates to stop. We tried creating a simple solution to recreate it, but cannot get it to happen.

Any ideas of where we should be looking?

It is a .net 7 app.

**Follow Up - 12/1/23**

After further investigation, it appears to be caused by including both the Application Insights SDK and the AutoMapper Collections Entity Framework Core extension library in the same application. I have been able to create a sample project that re-creates the issue and have created bugs in both communities.

Comment: Skimming the source code (https://github.com/Azure/AppConfiguration-DotnetProvider/blob/main/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration/AzureAppConfigurationProvider.cs) I'm seeing references to minimum cache timeouts, and push notifications? Is this relevant; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-dotnet-core-push-refresh?tabs=windowscommandprompt ?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman We are using the pull update method, not push. I have updated my question with results of more investigation. It appears to be caused by two libraries not playing nicely together.